# Ruby Rails: nested attributes different rows

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nested-attributes

With a Ruby on Rails 4 application I would like to save nested attributes for different rows, with different id's.

For example database model:

**weekresult**

```
id | weeknumber
---------------
1  | 2
2  | 3
```

**personal result**

```
id | weekresult_id | result 
---------------------------
1  | 1             | 4
2  | 2             | 5
```

Now I want to save personal results for both weekresult 1 and weekresult 2 in 1 form with nested attributes. So weekresults accepts_nested_attributes for personal results.

In weekresults_controller.rb I have

```
@weekresult = WeekResult.where(weeknumber: 2).first
```

In my form I have

```
form_for @weekresult do |f|
  f.fields_for :personal_results do |ff|
    //this is weeknumber 2, how to get weeknumber 3 as well?
  end
end
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: There is an excellent article by Peter Rhoades on how to use nested attributes in Rails 4 when you are dealing with several models on the same form: http://www.createdbypete.com/articles/working-with-nested-forms-and-a-many-to-many-association-in-rails-4/ I hope you find it helpful.

Comment: Nice article, but unfortunately it doesn't tackle my problem..

Comment: I added my comment as answer for readability.